# VBA: Trigger hidden rows based on yes/no responses to questions

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using excel to create a questionnaire, I need to program this questionnaire in a way that if a person answers Yes on a certain question it triggers sub-questions. These sub-questions are hidden rows and should appear only if the user answers Yes in that particular case. I have a solution but a very tedious one that requires programming every single cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$10" Then
    If Target.Value <> "Yes" Then Rows("5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    If Target.Value = "Yes" Then Rows("5").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
```

I was hoping to use a for loop to loop through each section and if the answer is Yes trigger rows to appear with the code below

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet").Range("C21:C32")
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
       'code here to show additional rows
        Rows("22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("23").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next cell
```

My problem with this is different "Yes" responses need to trigger different rows, For example if row 9 is a "Yes" trigger rows 10 and 11 and after this if 10 is yes trigger another row of sub-questions. I can easily use the Worksheet_Change method just modify it for every cel but this is very tedious. Is there any way I can do this in a for loop to make the code cleaner? I am eventually going to pass this on to another person to work on and I want to make sure I leave them the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: I think, you need to create an array of arrays. Say, `Dim arrRows(1 To 10, 1 To 2): arrRows(1,1) = "C21": arrRows(1,2) = Array(22, 23)`. Then, you can loop through this array: `For x = LBound(arr,1) To UBound(arr,1): Rows(arr(x,2)).Hidden = (Cells(arr(x,1)) = "Yes"): Next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one idea: give your "controller" cells a name such as (eg) "YES_10_11".
In the change event check to see if the Target range has a name, then parse out the comparison value and the rows to show/hide and apply the test.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim arr, rName, i, doHide As Boolean
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    On Error Resume Next
    rName = Target.Name.Name  ' e.g. YES_10_11
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Len(rName) > 0 Then
        arr = Split(rName, "_")
        doHide = (UCase(arr(0)) <> UCase(Target.Value))
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
            Me.Rows(arr(i)).Hidden = doHide
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

If your nesting goes deep though you might want to consider using a hidden sheet to store all of the relationships and loop over the whole thing for each change.

Comment: This was perfect, clean code and very efficient. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might just want to use `OFFSET()`:

```
For Each cell In Worksheets("CAP - Assessment").Range("C21:C32")
    If cell.Value = "Yes" Then
       'code here to show additional rows
        cell.Offset(1,0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        cell.Offset(2,0).EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
Next cell
```